# right turn stall, starving for fuel?

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, stall

I have a 1998 96" s&s with a super e carb - runs great straight up and leaning left turns but when I make a right hand turn it seems to starve for fuel and begins to stall. the turns are leaning, not handle bar turns. please help with any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please explain better what a S&S is? A lot of people on here do research on things which aren't their bailiwick. I'm assuming you're talking about a motorcycle, but that's not explicit either in your question or tags, so I'm trying to clarify. (Is this a Harley? 96" seems to imply this.) Which side of the tank is the fuel source? Is it opposite of the direction of lean? Are there multiple carbs? Have you had any maintenance done on the carb(s)? Is there a fuel filter?

Comment: 96" is the motor size of my bike, s&s is the motor and carb maker (single carb). I have dual tanks with dual fillers. right tank is plumbed into the left then to the petcock. petcock is on the left side. carb is on the stall side (right). fuel filter is a strainer in the tank. bike is 20 years old but maintained, this problem began with no changes to carb.

Comment: Great additional information. Appreciated. Have you done anything to ensure the crossover isn't plugged? Really, start with the simple things and work towards the harder things.

Comment: does it make a difference if the tanks are full or empty? It certainly *sounds* like you may just not be getting fuel to the petcock when leaned to the right. That would be consistent with how it is plumbed, since fuel would pool to the right on right turns.

Comment: at first the tanks were ~1/3 full, filled to top and still stumbles on rt. turns. I shut off the fuel and drained the carb bowl, sprayed card cleaner up inside then opened the fuel to flush - reassembled. pulled the air breather, started and sprayed cleaner into throat. when retested it was better for about a minute then back to stumbling. no hoses are kinked. idle is good and goes great when upright. thinking of pulling the petcock and checking the screen - thoughts???